# SELECT WHERE with updated_at is wrong

Tags: go, go-gorm

Expected this code result is `null` but I got not null.
`rDB.Where("user_id = ? AND updated_at > ?", userID, date).Find(&onedays)`

`date := "2018-01-04 23:18:00"` and there are some records in `Onedays` table.

```
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | save_state | date       | updated_at          |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      44 |          0 | 1514214001 | 2018-01-04 21:25:05 |
|  2 |      44 |          0 | 1514214001 | 2018-01-04 22:07:55 |
|  3 |      15 |          1 | 1514300400 | 2018-01-04 23:17:49 |
+----+---------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

return its code is:

```
{
"onedays": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 44,
        "save_state": false,
        "date": 1514214001,
        "updated_at": "2018-01-04T21:25:05+09:00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 44,
        "save_state": false,
        "date": 1514214001,
        "updated_at": "2018-01-04T22:07:55+09:00"
    }
],
"photos": null
}
```

But I exec this query, return is empty.
`SELECT * FROM Onedays WHERE user_id = 44 AND updated_at > '2018-01-04 23:18:00'`

Maybe this problem is occurred by gorm setting.
How I can solve this problem?

**UPDATE Pasted function code**

```
func getDiff(userID, date string) interface{} {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    var onedays []model.OnedayDiff
    var photos []model.PhotoDiff
    var resPhotos []model.PhotoDiff

    _, rDB := lib.DB()
    rDB.Where("user_id = ? AND updated_at > ?", userID, date).Find(&onedays)

    funcs := []func(){
        // Photo
        func() {
            rDB.Where("user_id = ?", userID).Find(&onedays)
            for _, v := range onedays {
                rDB.Where("oneday_id = ? AND updated_at > ?", v.ID, date).Find(&photos)
                resPhotos = append(resPhotos, photos...)
            }
        },
    }
    for _, sleep := range funcs {
        wg.Add(1)

        go func(function func()) {
            defer wg.Done()
            function()
        }(sleep)
    }
    wg.Wait()

    return map[string]interface{}{
        "onedays": onedays,
        "photos":  resPhotos,
    }
}
```

`photos` is correct. `onedays` is not correct...

Comment: Could you try to specify the timezone in your query? It may depend on the defaults. You also don't mention the driver/database. You should also try `db.Debug` (see [docs](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/advanced.html)) to log the actual query emitted.

Comment: @Marc Thanks comment. I don't know how to specify the timezone in the query... I set `?charset=utf8&parseTime=true&loc=Asia%2FTokyo` with `gorm.Open`

Comment: The output made no senses to me even taking time zone into consideration. Would you please check both `gorm` and `exec` with `date := "2018-01-04 22:00:00"` ?

Comment: I agree, the only way it makes sense is if the timezone used by gorm is +10 or more. This is why we need to be explicit about the timezone in queries, we don't know what the default timezone is.

Comment: @Marc however, as far as I know, Asia Tokyo is the same thing as `+9:00`. It is just weird.

Comment: I set mysql server timezone is JST / Asia/Tokyo. I checked now.

Comment: I have strange things. `Onedays` is not correct. But `Photos` is correct.
`Photos's updated_at` and `Onedays updated_at` is same column type....  Why...

Comment: `Onedays.updated_at` and `Photos.updated_at` is `updated_at datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: I did not spot the bug for `onedays` but for `photo`, your code is attempting to write to a same slice in different goroutines - which is a data race. You will be fine now because for now there is just one goroutine spawned.

Comment: Ah, I get it. You reused the `onedays` slice later, so it get overided.

Comment: @leafbebop oh... great thanks... yes I over wrote `onedays`...

Comment: That is why we always require codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
func() {
    rDB.Where("user_id = ?", userID).Find(&onedays)
    for _, v := range onedays {
        rDB.Where("oneday_id = ? AND updated_at > ?", v.ID, date).Find(&photos)
        resPhotos = append(resPhotos, photos...)
    }
},
```

You reused the slice `onedays` in the second line so it is not empty anymore. And in the 4th line, you are writing to `photos` async-ly, which cause a data race and will mess up if there is more than one goroutines.

You should redeclare both arrays in the func:

```
func() {
    var onedays []model.OnedayDiff
    var photos []model.PhotoDiff
    //other codes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the response obtained from GORM, the `update_at` values have a timezone included (the `+09:00` part), while the values in the database doesn't, so these are either handled as `UTC` or as the default timezone configured in your database server.

You should check the timezone differences between the DB and the host where the code is running.

Comment: Thanks comment. There is no different gorm setting and mysql server.